# How I can change the shortcut for chrome browser?

Tags: google-chrome, keyboard-shortcuts

I am using Chrome developer tool. When I work Everytime I press F12 to open chrome developer tool. The second f12 make it close.

I know it's work correctly but I want to changed it. What I need is change the shortcut key of Chrome to make thing work as my key shortcut.

How I can modify the f12 keys.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this, he seems to be doing exactly what you need.

https://superuser.com/questions/204770/how-to-change-a-shortcut-on-google-chrome

"There's an extension for remapping shortcuts that might be useful: https://chrome.google.com/extensions/detail/mgjjeipcdnnjhgodgjpfkffcejoljijf. Haven't tried it yet though."

Comment: Nope, the page doesn't exist.

Comment: Here is one that works: [AutoControl Shortcut Manager](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/lkaihdpfpifdlgoapbfocpmekbokmcfd)